# How would you approach finding the limit of the convergent sum 1/sqrt(n^2+k), k = 0 to k = n

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

I solved this question by using a wonky method and would like to hear different approaches to the solving the problem.

The task was to find out if the $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}$ converges and if so, what the sum converges to.

My wonky approach:
Found out that it convergences by creating a bigger sum that's easier to analyze. If the bigger sum converges => the smaller one does as well.

Bigger sum (n:terms): $n*\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} = \frac{n}{n}*\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}} $ which becomes 1 when n --> inf

Then I noticed that if you created a new sum with that smallest number in summation, it's limits is also 1

Then I saw that the last term converges aswell to 1

And therefor $ 1 \leq \lim Sn \leq 1$ <=> $\lim Sn = 1$

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: Not wonky at all, it's pretty standard. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you are correct, though you want to tidy a few things, such as the title which starts at $k=0$ while the question starts at $k=1$.

You have essentially said (using the easier $n^2+k > n^2$) $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1n}}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \le \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \le \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}= 1$$

and the limits of the left-hand and right-hand expressions are both $1$ as $n\to \infty$, so the limit of the middle expression $S_n$ sandwiched between them is also $1$.

Comment: Thank you! That was much better expressed.